# Are "install software on debian" - questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I flagged this one as off-topic [How to install a Lisp compiler?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9173/how-to-install-a-lisp-compiler) simply because I think that it is a general debian installation is off-topic.

The flag was declined. What did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 2):

The community decided that it was not off-topic via [review](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/review) (which gives me a warm feeling).

I would say that the question is on-topic as the installation is specific to the Raspberry Pi ([there is an arm version of the software](http://lispm.de/ccl)).

The question also has received several high quality answers and a moderate number of pageviews, making it a valuable addition.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It does, but if it on-topic because it is arm, then it makes even less sense that other arm-boards are off topic... :)

Comment: @Bex Questions about other arm boards are not questions related to the Raspberry Pi. Questions about arm software that someone is trying to install on their Raspberry Pi **is** related.